# How to get glaciered partitions in Glue table?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I'm looking for a way to get all table partitions that are in Glacier (archived). Is it possible to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by "get all table partitions"? Do you simply want a _list_ of partitions that have objects with a Storage Class of `Glacier`? Or do you want to _restore_ objects out of a `Glacier` Storage Class?

Comment: Yes, I need basically list all of partitions that have objects with a Storage Class of Glacier.

Comment: What is your definition of a "partition" in this context? If you are referring to Storage Classes, they are applied at the **object** level, not at a **directory**.

Comment: Okay, suppose I have a Glue table, partitioned by date column. In Glue I see a list of partitions, like date=2021-12-09/, date=2021-12-10/ ... The idea here is to get a list of Glue partitions (date=2021-12-..., date=2021-12-..., etc) that moved to Glacier and are not available for reading.

Comment: "Partitions" do not "move to Glacier". Instead, the _individual objects_ within a path might have moved to the Glacier storage class. So, you would need to check the Storage Class of all objects within each of those paths.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. I will try that approach.